# sass @each weird behaviour

Tags: sass, each

I have a weird problem. I have an `scss` object with some variables lets say:

```
$object = 'something' 'something2 'something3
```

Then I make a `loop`:

```
@each $some in $object { &.#{$some} {
        background-image: url('./../../../../assets/images/path/to/image/#{$some}/grey.svg');
        &:before {
          content: '#{$some}';
        } }
```

All the images I get by background images are the last image so they are from folder `something3` but `before` content gives me good result so for first `something1`, second `something2` etc. What is going one in here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i have found a solution...

```
        background-image: url('/../../../../assets/images/path/to/image/#{$some}/grey.svg');
```

Link should start from `/` not from `./`